# How to align my PHP version on my Mac with the PHP version installed in MAMP during Laravel installation?

Tags: php, macos, laravel, mamp

I am installing Laravel on Yosemite, with PHP installed under MAMP. I have already installed Composer in Terminal successfully.

The problem is that I have an older PHP version on my system (PHP `5.5.20 (cli)`), while the PHP version in MAMP is `5.6.7.` As a result, I have the following error message

`Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

`Problem 1`
    `- Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.16 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.16].`
    `- laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.`

So I followed this very useful link to install Laravel with Mamp, which includes a great post in the comments section from Phil T.
[link]http://shabeebk.com/blog/how-to-install-laravel-in-mamp/#comments

Given that mcrypt already exists in MAMP but not on my system, could you please detail the PATH command I should write to solve this?
Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think maybe you're using default php builded on yosemite.

1. Type `php --ini`  in terminal. you'll see information about php.ini file. for exp. 
   `Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
   Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
   Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
   Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)`

   2. Or type `which php` and you'll see path of php folder for exp.

   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php

If it's different than MAMP folder (if it's default - `/usr/bin/php`)
Change it to MAMP folder. To do it you need to change .bash_profile and add the MAMP version of PHP to the PATH variable.
You can edit .bash_profile with vim. Export the path variable with command

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php[php.version]/bin:$PATH
```

Finally, check again if php path is correct with commands `php --ini` or `which php`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! However, it triggered another problem when I tried to install laravel. I got    `[InvalidArgumentException]                 
  Project directory laratest/ is not empty.` Any advice?

Comment: delete old project directory and create new or create new project 
composer create-project laravel/laravel new-laravel-project
And try to use vm + vagrant + homestead instead of mamp or xampp - it's quietly better

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type the following commands :

```
$ echo "export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
```

and then type :

```
$ . ./.profile
```

Now , whe you type wish php , it tell you that the php used is Application/MAMP/..../php(your version)/bin/php